# Removing resource com.myapp.application:string/com_facebook_loginview_logged_in_using_facebook_f1gender without required default value

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-facebook

From one day to another I'm getting this error in my project:

```
Android resource linking failed
warn: removing resource com.myapp.application:string/com_facebook_loginview_logged_in_using_facebook_f1gender without required default value.
C:\Users\adamv\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\jetified-facebook-login-5.0.0.aar\93f0acb2a4de491348f33e5cac2f3dd4\res\drawable\com_facebook_button_login_background.xml:26: error: resource color/com_facebook_button_background_color_focused_disabled (aka com.myapp.application:color/com_facebook_button_background_color_focused_disabled) not found.
C:\Users\adamv\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\jetified-facebook-login-5.0.0.aar\93f0acb2a4de491348f33e5cac2f3dd4\res\drawable\com_facebook_button_login_background.xml:38: error: resource color/com_facebook_button_background_color_focused (aka com.myapp.application:color/com_facebook_button_background_color_focused) not found.
C:\Users\adamv\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\jetified-facebook-login-5.0.0.aar\93f0acb2a4de491348f33e5cac2f3dd4\res\drawable\com_facebook_button_login_background.xml:39: error: resource color/com_facebook_button_border_color_focused (aka com.myapp.application:color/com_facebook_button_border_color_focused) not found.
C:\a_projects\myapp-android\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_login.xml:75: error: resource drawable/com_facebook_button_icon_white (aka com.myapp.application:drawable/com_facebook_button_icon_white) not found.
C:\a_projects\myapp-android\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_register.xml:113: error: resource drawable/com_facebook_button_icon_white (aka com.myapp.application:drawable/com_facebook_button_icon_white) not found.
C:\a_projects\myapp-android\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_settings.xml:181: error: resource drawable/com_facebook_button_icon_white (aka com.myapp.application:drawable/com_facebook_button_icon_white) not found.
error: failed linking file resources.
```

I did nothing with the code. It is failing to build from one day to another.

In my gradle I use the following facebook libs:

```
  implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.0.0'
  implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:[5,6)'
```

These facebook libs were worked. I have another app where I use these, and that wan builds falwlessly.

Please, help if you can.

Answer (score 0):

See Prince's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57543127/android-gradle-fail-aapt-error-resource-color-com-facebook-button-background). If that does not work, you can manually set the colors.

```
<color name="com_facebook_button_background_color_focused_disabled">#3C5A99</color>
<color name="com_facebook_button_background_color_focused">#3C5A99</color>
<color name="com_facebook_button_border_color_focused">#3C5A99</color>
```